# ToolStripDropDownMenu remains open after Form minimize and restore

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have Window Forms application and I'm using ToolStripDropDown as context menu for my form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ToolStripDropDownMenu _formContextMenu = null;        

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _formContextMenu = new ToolStripDropDownMenu();
        _formContextMenu.Items.Add("Item1");
        _formContextMenu.Items.Add("Item2");
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            _formContextMenu.Show(e.Location);
        }
        else
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        _formContextMenu.Close();
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
}
```

First I click on form with Right Mouse button to show context menu. After that I press Win+D (minimize all windows) and then open my application again. Context menu remains opened and also it doesn't close when I click on form. I even can move form to other place but it will still remains opened. 
I also tried to close it with different reasons.

```
    _formContextMenu.Close(ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.AppClicked);
    _formContextMenu.Close(ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.AppFocusChange);
    _formContextMenu.Close(ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.CloseCalled);
    _formContextMenu.Close(ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked);
    _formContextMenu.Close(ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.Keyboard);
```

Doesn't help. 
Can someone help with this issue?

Comment: Off-Topic but, Why don't you use `ContextMenuStrip`? Also you should show it this way `_formContextMenu.Show(this,e.Location);`. Also you don't need to write code for showing it, you can just set `ContextMenuStrip` property of form.

Comment: @RezaAghaei. Thanks for your replay. 
ContextMenuStrip have the same behavior.
`_formContextMenu.Show(this,e.Location);` - doesn't change behavior also.

Comment: Yes I know, but just wanted to introduce `ContextMenuStrip` component and property of form  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this workaround for the problem and it works properly:

```
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        //_formContextMenu or this.contextMenuStrip1

        this.contextMenuStrip1.Visible = true; 
        this.contextMenuStrip1.Close();
    }
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);
}
```

While this problem also occurs for `ContextMenuStrip` but if there is not specific goal for using `ToolStripDropDownMenu` you can use `ContextMenuStrip` component and Set `ContextMenuStrip` property of form. This way you don't need to write code to show context menu.

But if in any reason you preferred showing in code, consider showing the context menu/ dropdown menu this way: `yourContextMenu.Show(this,e.Location);`

Comment: Thank you! it works. Maybe you also know the reason of such behavior

Comment: Seems that `Close()` doesn't work as expected when `ContextMenu` is already hidden.

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment I have no idea about the main reason of the behavior and just followed my guesses. I'll share any finding if I found any evidence about my guess :) But if you really care about the reason, you may want take a look at [ToolStripDropDown.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolStripDropDown.cs)